# $(document).ready(function not loading unless refreshed

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I am using  jQuery and the $(document).ready event. when i load in IE8 i get an error "Object doesn't support this property or method". When i refresh it works fine. Here is my code:

```
    <script language="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
       {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
       document.getElementById("loginbox").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
    }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","loginform.php",true);
       xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       xmlhttp.send();
   });
  </script>
```

I have the following in my head tag:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
```

Any help would be appreciated i have tried $(window).load and others.

Comment: You *do* realize that jQuery can send AJAX requests via the `$.post()`, `$.get()`, and `$.ajax()` functions?

Comment: yes, i'm working on hone the code to that eventually, this interacts with a filemaker server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the jQuery library when you include it, as you are using only the `$(document).ready()` function.

Try this code (it accomplishes the exact same thing as yours):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.post('loginform.php', $('#id_of_your_login_form').serialize(), function(response) {
    $('#loginbox').html(response);
  });
});
```

---

This line also might be problematic:

```
<script language="text/javascript">
```

You are specifying the `type`, not the `language`. Try this one instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: I used the $.get method since i wasn't passing anything to the file. worked like a charm. thank you. the Type/language issue was from trial and error before. that you for correcting me.

Comment: No problem. jQuery is kind of like writing plain English ;) You can just omit the `.serialize()` thing if you aren't posting anything. That just takes your form's contents and serializes them, like `bar=asd&foo=asd%20as`. It's quite handy.